# как соединить sccs и html через gulp

Tags: html, css, gulp

где писать код css? я создал проект на gulp и не понимаю как связать css и html

Comment: Так css или scss? Или вообще какой-то sccs?

Comment: scss, извиняюсь

Answer (score 0):

Нужно ваш scss компилировать через gulpfile.js в css файл.
Для этого (если не установлен) через пакет менеджер устанавливаете sass, в gulpfile.js подключаете.
потом создаете таск

```
gulp.task('имя-таска', function() {
return gulp.src('путь к scss относительно gulpfile.js')
.pipe(sass())
.pipe(gulp.dest('путь к директории с css файлами')
});
```

после чего подключаете готовый css в html